# Getting Name initials using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to extract initials from a string, like:

```
Name = FirstName LastName 
Initials =  FL
```

I can get the above result using this,

```js
const initials = item
    .FirstName
    .charAt(0)
    .toUpperCase() +
  
    item
    .LastName
    .charAt(0)
    .toUpperCase();
```

But now my requirements are changed as if name only consist of 1 word or more then 2, so in following cases how can I get initials as per my requirements,

```
FullName =  FU
FirstName MiddleName LastName = FL
1stName 2ndName 3rdName 4thName 5thName = 15
```

**How can I get above initials from a string in JS?**

Also now I only have `item.Name` string as an input

Comment: Only answer to OP's full question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763497/1602301

Comment: If someone is looking for just 1 character for single word with spaces handled - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66239174/1891625

Comment: this does assume that all names are Firstname MiddleName Surname, but there's the edge case of Dutch surnames such as "de Suza", where the de is part of the surname, so really I feel like the case was a bad case from the start

Answer (score 92):

Why no love for regex?

*Updated to support unicode characters and use ES6 features*

```js
let name = 'ÇFoo Bar 1Name too ÉLong';
let rgx = new RegExp(/(\p{L}{1})\p{L}+/, 'gu');

let initials = [...name.matchAll(rgx)] || [];

initials = (
  (initials.shift()?.[1] || '') + (initials.pop()?.[1] || '')
).toUpperCase();

console.log(initials);
```

Comment: Note that this does not handle a one-word name well. `"Prince"` has the initials `"PUNDEFINED"`

Comment: @thetallweeks You're right, I edited the code to handle one-word name and empty strings too.

Comment: This is for names that only uses the basic 26 alphabets. Does not support names with diacritics.

Comment: "Why no love for regex?" Because regex is usually less readable and more prone to being incorrect for corner cases. Just look at the comments on this answer for proof.

Comment: Doesn't work for instances where the first name is already an initial. E.g. "K Mehta" should result in "KM"

Comment: This is not working for me for names like `Ca**ya Wh**e`. Actual name is `Camaya White`.

Comment: This could be much simpler using string and array prototype methods.

Answer (score 58):

You can use this shorthand js

```
"FirstName LastName".split(" ").map((n)=>n[0]).join(".");
```

To get only First name and Last name you can use this shorthand function

```
(fullname=>fullname.map((n, i)=>(i==0||i==fullname.length-1)&&n[0]).filter(n=>n).join(""))
("FirstName MiddleName OtherName LastName".split(" "));
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the original question - if you have a MiddleName in there, this returns 'FML'.

Comment: maybe replace `.join(".")` with .reduce((acc, cur) => acc+=cur + '.', '')`, this way You have dot at the end

Answer (score 55):

Check the `getInitials` function below:

```js
var getInitials = function (string) {
    var names = string.split(' '),
        initials = names[0].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    
    if (names.length > 1) {
        initials += names[names.length - 1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    }
    return initials;
};

console.log(getInitials('FirstName LastName'));
console.log(getInitials('FirstName MiddleName LastName'));
console.log(getInitials('1stName 2ndName 3rdName 4thName 5thName'));
```

The functions split the input string by spaces:

```
names = string.split(' '),
```

Then get the first name, and get the first letter:

```
initials = names[0].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
```

If there are more then one name, it takes the first letter of the last name (the one in position `names.length - 1`):

```
if (names.length > 1) {
    initials += names[names.length - 1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 52):

**Get First and Last Initial:** `John Doe Smith => JS`

```
name.match(/(\b\S)?/g).join("").match(/(^\S|\S$)?/g).join("").toUpperCase()
```

**Get All Initials:**  `"John Doe Smith" => "JDS"`

```
name.match(/(\b\S)?/g).join("").toUpperCase()
```

**Get First and Last except get First 2 in case there is only first. (OP's question)**

`John => JO` and `"John Doe Smith" => "JS"`

```
name.match(/(^\S\S?|\b\S)?/g).join("").match(/(^\S|\S$)?/g).join("").toUpperCase()
```

**International Version:** `"Störfried Würgekloß" => "SW"`

```
name.match(/(^\S\S?|\s\S)?/g).map(v=>v.trim()).join("").match(/(^\S|\S$)?/g).join("").toLocaleUpperCase()
```

---

**Note:** If the name contains `,` or other non word characters, you might use `/w` instead of `/S` or sanitize it beforehand

Comment: this solution doesn't yet work with non-english characters such as german umlauts. currently it will produce wrong initials.

Comment: @LarsBlumberg can you provide an example name

Comment: `"Störfried Würgekloß"`. Current answer yields `"SSS"` as initials. Should be: `"SW"`

Comment: @LarsBlumberg added to the answer

Answer (score 25):

## Common Avatar Use-case

Just surprised that none of the answers put [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to good use.

```
const getInitials = (fullName) => {
  const allNames = fullName.trim().split(' ');
  const initials = allNames.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if(index === 0 || index === allNames.length - 1){
      acc = `${acc}${curr.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}`;
    }
    return acc;
  }, '');
  return initials;
}
```

Run the snippet below to check the initials for different use cases -

```js
const testNames = [
  'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian dumbledore', // AD
  'Harry Potter',  // HP
  'Ron', // R
  '', // <empty>
  'Çigkofte With Érnie', // ÇÉ
  'Hermione ', // H  (Notice that there is a space after the name) 
  'Neville LongBottom ' // NL (space after name is trimmed)
]

const getInitials = (fullName) => {
  const allNames = fullName.trim().split(' ');
  const initials = allNames.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if(index === 0 || index === allNames.length - 1){
      acc = `${acc}${curr.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}`;
    }
    return acc;
  }, '');
  return initials;
}


console.log(testNames.map(getInitials));
```

##### Note

This one is for a widely used case for displaying names in Avatars, where you wouldn't want first name initial to be repeated twice and want to restrict the initials to a max of 2 letters

Comment: This is the winner for me.  Doesn't require me installing any unicode REGEX stuff to make it work on ES5 browsers!

Answer (score 10):

You can use below one line logic:

```
"FirstName MiddleName LastName".split(" ").map((n,i,a)=> i === 0 || i+1 === a.length ? n[0] : null).join("");
```

Answer (score 8):

##### There are some other answers which solve your query but are slightly complicated. Here's a more readable solution which covers most edge cases.

As your full name can have any number of words(middle names) in it, our best bet is to spit it into an array and get the initial characters from the first and last words in that array and return the letters together.

Also if your 'fullName' contains only one word, word at `array[0]` and `array[array.length - 1]` would be the same word, so we are handling that if the first `if`.

```
function nameToInitials(fullName) {
  const namesArray = fullName.trim().split(' ');
  if (namesArray.length === 1) return `${namesArray[0].charAt(0)}`;
  else return `${namesArray[0].charAt(0)}${namesArray[namesArray.length - 1].charAt(0)}`;
}
```

Sample outputs :

`> nameToInitials('Prince')` // "P"

`> nameToInitials('FirstName LastName')` // "FL"

`> nameToInitials('1stName 2ndName 3rdName 4thName 5thName')`
// "15"

Answer (score 7):

```
const initial = username.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('')
```

Comment: `username.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('').toUpperCase()` to convert to uppercase

Comment: It doesn't work with accents. "John Céna" returns "JN" instead of "JC".

Comment: thats uncommon case bro, you can replace \w with character class instead if you want

Answer (score 6):

```
'Aniket Kumar Agrawal'.split(' ').map(x => x.charAt(0)).join('').substr(0, 2).toUpperCase()
```

Comment: Perhaps provide an explanation to what this is doing?

Answer (score 5):

You can do a function for that:

```
var name = 'Name';

function getInitials( name,delimeter ) {

    if( name ) {

        var array = name.split( delimeter );

        switch ( array.length ) {

            case 1:
                return array[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
                break;
            default:
                return array[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + array[ array.length -1 ].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5v3n2f95/1/

Answer (score 4):

+ efficient
+ no loops
+ simplified branching (ternary operator only)
+ handles no-space cases (prints 2 chars)
+ no array memory allocation (actually no array processing)
- requires trimmed string input

```js
function getInitials(name) {
    const hasTokens = name.indexOf(' ') !== -1
    return name.substring(0, hasTokens ? 1 : 2) + (hasTokens ? name.charAt(name.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) : '')
}

console.log(getInitials("A B"), 'AB')
console.log(getInitials("Abc Def"), 'AD')
console.log(getInitials("Abc Xyz"), 'AX')
console.log(getInitials("S Xyz"), 'SX')
console.log(getInitials("SXyz "), 'SX')
console.log(getInitials("T30"), 'T3')
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const getInitials = name => name
  .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ ]/ig, '')        // taking care of accented characters as well
  .replace(/ +/ig, ' ')                     // replace multiple spaces to one
  .split(/ /)                               // break the name into parts
  .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item[0], '') // assemble an abbreviation from the parts
  .concat(name.substr(1))                   // what if the name consist only one part
  .concat(name)                             // what if the name is only one character
  .substr(0, 2)                             // get the first two characters an initials
  .toUpperCase();                           // uppercase, but you can format it with CSS as well

console.log(getInitials('A'));
console.log(getInitials('Abcd'));
console.log(getInitials('Abcd Efgh'));
console.log(getInitials('Abcd    Efgh    Ijkl'));
console.log(getInitials('Abcd Efgh Ijkl Mnop'));
console.log(getInitials('Ábcd Éfgh Ijkl Mnop'));
console.log(getInitials('Ábcd - Éfgh Ijkl Mnop'));
console.log(getInitials('Ábcd / # . - , Éfgh Ijkl Mnop'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar but slightly neater version of @njmwas answer:

```
let name = 'Fred Smith';
let initials = name.split(' ').reduce((acc, subname) =>
    acc + subname[0], '')
console.log(initials) // FS
```

Or, to include the abbreviation dots:

```
let name = 'Fred Smith';
let initials = name.split(' ').reduce((acc, subname) =>
    acc + subname[0] + '.', '')
console.log(initials) // F.S.
```

Comment: Great work! I converted it to a function and added trim to make sure it doesn't show 'undefined' incase last name is empty ```export const getNameInitials = name => {
    return name.trim().split(' ').reduce((acc, subname) =>
        acc + subname[0], '')
}
}```

Comment: Trim is a good addition since it also accounts for any double spaces which are incorrectly added by an end user. However, I wouldn't expect last name to be empty for a full name and still have a space unless the names were stored separately in the database, in which case I think you'd be better off using a function which took the names as arguments rather than concatenating the strings first.

Answer (score 2):

Easier with map function:

```
var name = "First Last";
var initials = Array.prototype.map.call(name.split(" "), function(x){ return x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();}).join('');
```

Comment: This also doesn't quite answer the original question - if you have a MiddleName in there, this returns 'FML'.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this today to act as method in my React code. I was getting the user name from the state as props. After that I just passed my method inside my component's props.

```
getUserInitials() {
  const fullName = this.props.user.name.split(' ');
  const initials = fullName.shift().charAt(0) + fullName.pop().charAt(0);
  return initials.toUpperCase();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this;

```
    function initials(name){

      //splits words to array
      var nameArray = name.split(" ");

      var initials = '';

      //if it's a single word, return 1st and 2nd character
      if(nameArray.length === 1) {
        return nameArray[0].charAt(0) + "" +nameArray[0].charAt(1);
      }else{
         initials = nameArray[0].charAt(0);
      }
      //else it's more than one, concat the initials in a loop
      //we've gotten the first word, get the initial of the last word


      //first word
      for (i = (nameArray.length - 1); i < nameArray.length; i++){
        initials += nameArray[i].charAt(0);
      }
     //return capitalized initials
     return initials.toUpperCase();
   }
```

You can then use the function like so;

```
  var fullname = 'badmos tobi';
  initials(fullname); //returns BT 

  var surname = 'badmos';
  initials(surname); //returns BA

  var more = 'badmos gbenga mike wale';
  initials(more); //returns BW;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is actually a perfect function, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses Array capabilities, Arrow function and ternary operator to achieve the goal in one line.
If name is single word, just take first two chars, but if more, then take 1st chars of first and last names.
(thanks omn for reminding single word name use case)

```
string.trim().split(' ').reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => acc + (arr.length > 1 ? (idx == 0 || idx == arr.length - 1 ? cur.substring(0, 1) : '') : cur.substring(0, 2)), '').toUpperCase()
```

Comment: You answer would be much better if it explained what the code does and why rather than just providing a snippet. I also don't think it actually has the desired behavior. It looks like it returns the first character of the first and last words, but it does not return the first two characters of the first word if it is the only word.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first name and last name initials, try using the function below.

```
const getInitials = string => {
    const names = string.split(' ');
    const initials = names.map(name => name.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
    if (initials.length > 1) {
        return `${initials[0]}${initials[initials.length - 1]}`;
    } else {
        return initials[0];
    }
};
console.log(getInitials("1stName 2ndName 3rdName 4thName 5thName")); // 15
console.log(getInitials("FirstName MiddleName LastName")); // FL
```

WHAT HAPPENED: The function splits the incoming string, ignores any name between the first & last names and returns their initials. In the case a single name is entered, a single initial is returned. I hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getInitials(name) {
  return (
    name
      .match(/(?<=\s|^)\p{L}\p{Mn}*/gu)
      ?.filter((el, i, array) => i === 0 || i === array.length - 1)
      .join("") || ""
  );
}

console.log(getInitials('ÇFoo Bar 1Name too ÉLong'));
console.log(getInitials('Q̈lice Hwerty')); // Q is followed by U+0308 (Combining Diaeresis)
console.log(getInitials('A Foo'));
console.log(getInitials('Bob'));
```

Safari doesn't yet support lookbehinds in regexes (see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)), so if Safari support is needed, it can be rewritten this way:

```js
function getInitials(name) {
  return (
    name
      .match(/(\s|^)\p{L}\p{Mn}*/gu)
      ?.filter((el, i, array) => i === 0 || i === array.length - 1)
      .map(el => el.trimStart())
      .join("") || ""
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const name = 'First Second Third'

name
    .split(' ')
    .slice(0, 2) // <= optional if only two letters are desired
    .map((name) => name[0])
    .join('')

// FS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const getInitials = name => {
    let initials = '';
    name.split(' ').map( subName => initials = initials + subName[0]);
    return initials;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var personName = "FirstName MiddleName LastName";
var userArray = personName.split(" ");
var initials = [];
if(userArray.length == 1){
 initials.push(userArray[0][0].toUpperCase() + userArray[0][1]).toUpperCase();}
else if(userArray.length > 1){
initials.push(userArray[0][0].toUpperCase() + userArray[userArray.length-1][0].toUpperCase());}
console.log(initials);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for majority of the cases including middle names and first name only (extension on @njmwas answer).

```
const initialArr = name.split(" ").map((n)=>n[0]);
const init = (initialArr.length > 1)? `${initialArr[0]}${initialArr[initialArr.length - 1]}` : initialArr[0];
const initials = init.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way using **ES6 Destructering**:

```
const getInitials = string =>
  string
    .split(' ')
    .map(([firstLetter]) => firstLetter)
    .filter((_, index, array) => index === 0 || index === array.length - 1)
    .join('')
    .toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS THE SIMPLE UTILITY METHOD THAT HELPS TO GET THE INITIALS OF THE NAME
BY SIMPLY PASSING THE NAME TO getInitials function
// eg getInitials("harry potter")  ==> "HP"**

```
const getInitials = (name) => {
  var parts = name.split(' ')
  var initials = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i].length > 0 && parts[i] !== '') {
      initials += parts[i][0]
    }
  }
  return initials.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something more functional: D

```
  const getInitials = (string) => {
        const [firstname, lastname] = string.toUpperCase().split(' ');
        const initials = firstname.substring(0, 1);
        return lastname
          ? initials.concat(lastname.substring(0, 1))
          : initials.concat(firstname.substring(1, 2));
      };

console.log(getInitials('FirstName LastName')); // FL
console.log(getInitials('FirstName MiddleName LastName')); // FM
console.log(getInitials('FirstName')); // FI
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getInitials = function (string) {
var names = string.split(' '),
initials = names[0].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+'.';

if (names.length > 1) {
initials += names[names.length - 2].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+'.';
}
return initials=initials+names[names.length - 1].toUpperCase();
}
```

console.log(getInitials('Rama Krishna Narayan'));

```js
var getInitials = function (string) {
    var names = string.split(' '),
    initials = names[0].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+'.';
    
    if (names.length > 1) {
    initials += names[names.length - 2].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+'.';
    }
    return initials=initials+names[names.length - 1].toUpperCase();
    }
 console.log(getInitials('Rama Krishna Narayan'));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score 0):

A better way.

```
nameToInitials(name: string): string {
    const portions = name.split(' ')
        .map(val => val[0]);

    return portions.slice(0, 2)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, '').toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I misunderstand something, but most answers are so.... complicated.

My solution is (for international, actually hungarian names):

```
var regex = /[A-ZÍÉÁŰŐÚÖÜÓ]{1}/g
var monogram = 'Üveges Tóth Ödön'.match(regex).join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### There are many complicated answers here...

## Simpler solution with Clean code!

I know this question has been around for a while, but I believe this solution is good enough to share with you :)

My goal with this code is to create something that is both intelligent and easy to read.

```js
const names = [
  'Crystals', // -> CR
  'undisclosed desires', // -> UD
  'Feel so Close - Radio Edit', // -> FE
  ' ', // -> empty
  'Faint ', // -> FA .: Note the space after the name
]

function getInitials(fullName) {
  const [firstName, ...restNames] = fullName.toUpperCase().trim().split(' ')

  if (!restNames.length) {
    return firstName.substring(0,2)
  }

  const firstNameInitial = firstName[0]
  const lastNameInitial = restNames.pop()[0]

  return `${firstNameInitial}${lastNameInitial}`
}

console.log(names.map(getInitials))
```

The first line, transforms the string to uppercase, remove unwanted spaces (at the begginning and end) and split the name creating an array. Using the destructuring we recover the `firstName` and place the rest into a constant called `restNames`

```js
const [firstName, ...restNames] = fullName.toUpperCase().trim().split(' ')
```

after that, we check if there's other names besides the first name, if not, we return the first two letters from it ending the function execution

```js
if (!restNames.length) {
  return firstName[0].substring(0,2)
}
```

If we found out that restNames contains other names, we get the first name and the last name initials

```
const firstNameInitial = firstName[0]
const lastNameInitial = restNames.pop()[0]
```

Finally, we return the initials!

```
return `${firstNameInitial}${lastNameInitial}`
```

This code aims to be clear and efficient in providing the desired result

Answer (score -1):

just updated Andrea's version:

```
var getInitials = function (string) {
   var initials = "";
   var names = string.split(' ');
   for (n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
        initials += names[n].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    }
    return initials;
};
```

if **string** includes LastName, just change *names.length* to **names.length-1** to ignore lastname

Answer (score -1):

Using some es6 functionality:

```js
const testNameString = 'Hello World';
const testNameStringWeird = 'Hello  darkness My  - Óld Friend Nikolaus Koster-Walder ';
const getInitials = nameString =>{
       const regexChar = /\D\w+/
       return nameString
        .trim() //remove trailing spaces
        .split(' ') // splits on spaces
        .filter(word => word.length > 0) // strip out double spaces
        .filter(word => regexChar.test(word)) // strip out special characters
        .map(word => word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()) // take first letter from each word and put into array
}
console.log('name:',testNameString,'\n initials:',getInitials(testNameString));
console.log('name:',testNameStringWeird,'\n initials:',getInitials(testNameStringWeird));
```

Answer (score -2):

I saw a bunch of overcomplicated ways to do this. 
I'm really more into simplifying things as much as possible, and enhance things using composition or currying.

Here are my 2 cents:

```js
// Helpers

const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
const reverseText = (text = '')=> text.split('').reverse().join('');

const getInitialsDelimitBy = (delimiter = ' ') => (displayName = '') =>
  displayName
    .trim()
    .split(delimiter)
    .reduce((acc, value) => `${acc}${value.charAt(0)}`, '')
    .toUpperCase();

const getInitialsDelimitByComas = pipe(
  getInitialsDelimitBy(','), 
  reverseText
);

const getInitialsDelimitBySpaces = getInitialsDelimitBy(' '); // Not necessary because of the default but clearer 

const comaInitials = getInitialsDelimitByComas('Wayne, Bruce') // BW
const spaceInitials = getInitialsDelimitBySpaces('Bruce Wayne') // BW
```

For your specific case I would suggest something like this:

```
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);

const nameProcessor = {
  single: (name = '') =>
    name
      .trim()
      .substring(0, 2)
      .toUpperCase(),
  multiple: pipe(
    name => name.trim().split(' '),
    words => `${words[0].charAt(0)}${words[words.length - 1].charAt(0)}`,
    initials => initials.toUpperCase(),
  ),
};

const getInitials = (displayName = '') => 
  displayName.split(' ').length === 1 
    ? nameProcessor.single(displayName) 
    : nameProcessor.multiple(displayName)

getInitials('FullName') // FU
getInitials('FirstName MiddleName LastName') // FL
getInitials('1stName 2ndName 3rdName 4thName 5thName') // 15
```

I hope that helps =D