# JavaScript full name array initials

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const name = ['John Doe', 'Jack Lock', 'Nick Load'];
const initials = name.map([a]) => a);
console.log(initials);
```

I'm trying to print array items initials, but I only got first letter of the items.

This is what I'm getting
[image]

What I need

```json
['J.D', 'J.L', 'N.L']
```

Comment: So, instead of destructuring the string and getting the first char, get the full name, split on the whitespace and then get the first letter of each.

Comment: I don't see how you get "P A I" from this code. The code isn't even trying to create any initials…

Comment: There isn't even a `p` in any of those names ;)

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting Name initials using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076177)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: `['John Doe', 'Jack Lock', 'Nick Load'].map(t => t.match(/[A-Z]/g).join('.'))`

Comment: Part of the issue is the syntax on the second line. You are missing parentheses. You have a sing open paren after `map` which is closed by the close paren after `[a]`. 'm assuming you were going for this: `const initials = name.map(([a]) => a);`. But this is not going to fix it either.  you need something like the answer 0stone0 provided.

Answer (score 1):

- `map()` to loop over the array
- `split()` to get first and last name
- `map()` again over both names
- `substring()` to get the first char
- `join()` to concat again

```js
const name = ['John Doe', 'Jack Lock', 'Nick Load'];

const initials = name.map(n => n.split(' ').map(s => s.substring(0, 1)).join('.'));

console.log(initials);
```

```json
[
  "J.D",
  "J.L",
  "N.L"
]
```